# Convert an Object to hash then save it to user's column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Could not find nothing close to what I'm trying to do. I want to store an object into a user's column. That column is in the form of an array:

```
#postgres
def change
  add_column :users, :interest, :string, array: true, default: '{}'
end
```

I have another model called FooBar setup for other use. Each user has unique information inside as I've added a `user_id` key.

Im trying to make more sense:

```
def interest
 @user = User.find(current_user.id ) # I need the logged in user's id
 @support = Support.find(params[:id]) # I need the post's id they are on
 u = FooBar.new
 u.user_id = @user
 u.support_id = @support
 u.save # This saves a new Foo object..this is what I want

 @user.interest.push(FooBar.find(@user)) # This just stores the object name itself ;)
end
```

So when I call `u1 = FooBar.find(1)` I get value return in hash. I want when I say `u1.interest` I get the same. The reason is, I need to target those keys on the user ie: `u1.interest[0].support_id`

Is this possible? I've looked over my basic ruby docs and nothing works. Oh..if I passed `FooBar.find(@user).inspect` I get the hash but not the way I want it.

Im trying to do something similar to [stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby#retrieve_customer). Look at their `data` key. That's a hash.

**Edit for Rich' answer:**

I have, literally, a model called `UserInterestSent` model and table:

```
class UserInterestSent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :support # you can call this post
end

class CreateUserInterestSents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :user_interest_sents do |t|
      t.integer :user_id # user's unique id to associate with post (support)
      t.integer :interest_sent, :default => 0 # this will manually set to 1
      t.integer :support_id, :default => 0 # id of the post they're on

      t.timestamps # I need the time it was sent/requested for each user
    end
  end
end
```

I call `interest` `interest_already_sent`:

**supports_controller.rb:**

```
  def interest_already_sent
    support = Support.find(params[:id])
    u = UserInterestSent.new(
      {
        'interest_sent' => 1, # they can only send one per support (post)
        'user_id' => current_user.id, # here I add the current user
        'support_id' => support.id, # and the post id they're on
      }) 
        current_user.interest << u # somewhere this inserts twice with different timestamps
  end
```

And the `interest` not **interests**, column:

```
class AddInterestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :interest, :text
  end
end
```

Comment: have you tried using `.to_json` on the object and saving that?

Comment: @martincarlin87 yes but I cant get to any keys ie `u1.interest[0].support_id`

Comment: @Sylar could you explain why you aren't using a regular foreign key relationship (e.g. foobar_id as a field on the user model)? Or if you need to preserve the Foobar's state, you could have a subclass called UserFooBar that stores the data exactly as it was stored with no updates.

Comment: What kind of SQL are you using? PGSQL allows this out of the box I think

Comment: That's correct. Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## HStore

I remembered there's a PGSQL datatype called **[`hStore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html)**:

> This module implements the hstore data type for storing sets of
>   key/value pairs within a single `PostgreSQL` value. This can be useful
>   in various scenarios, such as rows with many attributes that are
>   rarely examined, or semi-structured data. Keys and values are simply
>   text strings.

[Heroku supports it](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/3/14/introducing_keyvalue_data_storage_in_heroku_postgres) and I've seen it used on another live application I was observing.

It won't store your object in the same way as `Stripe`'s `data` attribute (for that, you'll just need to use `text` and save the object itself), but you *can* store a series of `key:value` pairs (JSON).

I've never used it before, but I'd imagine you can send a JSON object to the column, and it will allow you to to use the attributes you need. There's a [good tutorial here](https://alybadawy.com/post/using-postgres-hstore-datatype-with-ruby-on-rails), and [Rails documentation here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#hstore):

```
# app/models/profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Profile.create(settings: { "color" => "blue", "resolution" => "800x600" })

profile = Profile.first
profile.settings # => {"color"=>"blue", "resolution"=>"800x600"}

profile.settings = {"color" => "yellow", "resolution" => "1280x1024"}
profile.save!
```

--

This means you should be able to just pass JSON objects to your `hstore` column:

```
#app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
   def update 
      @profile = current_user.profile
      @profile.update profile_params
   end

   private

   def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:x, :y, :z) #-> z = {"color": "blue", "weight": "heavy"}
   end
end
```

---

As per your comments, it seems to me that you're trying to store "interest" in a `User` from another model.

My first interpretation was that you wanted to store a *hash* of information in your `@user.interests` column. Maybe you'd have `{name: "interest", type: "sport"}` or something.

From your comments, it seems like you're wanting to store associated objects/data in this column. If this is the case, the way you're doing it should be to use an [ActiveRecord association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

If you don't know what this is, it's essentially a way to connect two or more models together through foreign keys in your DB. The way you set it up will determine what you can store & how...

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :interests,
      class_name: "Support",
      join_table: :users_supports,
      foreign_key: :user_id,
      association_foreign_key: :support_id
end

#app/models/support.rb
class Support < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users,
      class_name: "Support",
      join_table: :users_supports,
      foreign_key: :support_id,
      association_foreign_key: :user_id
end

#join table = users_supports (user_id, support_id)
```

by using this, you can populate the `.interests` or `.users` methods respectively:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :supports do
   post :interest #-> url.com/supports/:support_id/interest
end

#app/controllers/supports_controller.rb
class SupportsController < ApplicationController
   def interest
       @support = Support.find params[:support_id] # I need the post's id they are on
       current_user.interests << @support
   end
end
```

This will allow you to call `@user.interests` and bring back a collection of `Support` objects.

---

Okay, look.

What I suggested was an *alternative* to using `interest` column.

**You seem to want to store a series of hashes for an associated model. This is exactly what `many-to-many` relationships are for.**

The reason your data is being populated twice is because you're invoking it twice (`u=` is creating a record directly on the join model, and then you're inserting more data with `<<`).

I must add that in *both* instances, the *correct* behaviour is occurring; the join model is being populated, allowing you to call the associated objects.

What you're going for is something like this:

[image]

```
def interest_already_sent
    support = Support.find params[:id]
    current_user.interests << support
end
```

When using the method I recommended, **get rid of the `interest` column**.

You can call `.interests` *through* your *join table*.

When using the code above, it's telling Rails to insert the `support` object (IE `support_id` into the `current_user` (IE `user_id`) `interests` association (populated with the `UserInterestSelf` table).

This will basically then add a new record to this table with the `user_id` of `current_user` and the `support_id` of `support`.

Comment: Would this overwrite the `interest` hash? I dont want that.

Comment: I don't think so. If it's a pure hash, it should be set

Comment: Ok. The first answer overwrites the entire hash. I'll try your answer now then let you know.

Comment: Hi. This overwrites the hash. Ive tried it in the rails c :(

Comment: The question was how to store the hash, not whether it is overwritten. Can you give me a breakdown of what you mean by it being overwritten so we can fix it?

Comment: Whenever I call the `interest` method, it overwrites the existing hash. A clear example is that I'm passing `FooBar` inside `@user.interest`

Comment: Okay, so `interest` is meant to store the hash of the entire `User` object. What are the results of the answers we've written? When you say "overwritten", what do you get?

Comment: Interest is a column on the Users table. I want to keep track of how many interest was sent on a post etc for that user. When I called the interest method, only one hash is shown. If I call that method, say 5 times, I should see 5 hashes.

Comment: `FooBar` has all the interest hashes, yes..I need all the the current_user hashes to be on a User column

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure this is what you want? I mean, this sounds like you could benefit from a foreign key? I don't want to insult your intelligence; if you'd like me to give you an example, I'll gladly post an update

Comment: I have a foreign key on `FooBar` as `user_id` but I don't mind seeing what you have.

Comment: All done, I go and eat now so let me know and I'll see when I come back if you need more help

Comment: Ok we are now getting there :) When I call the interest method, I'm getting duplicate hashes? Where is that coming from?

Comment: Should not this, "u", be @support: `current_user.interests << u`?

Comment: You're getting duplicate hashes because they're called a "collection". I can find info on it if you need. And yes I just changed the code to the correct version

Comment: Rich, I see you're in the UK. I dont mind jumping on a train to waste 5mins of your time tbh. lol I still cant get rid of the duplications each time i call the function

Comment: Yes it worked but just the duplicate inserts for `FooBar`

Comment: In the `current_user.interests <<` part?

Comment: And you're using the code that I provided, or is it modified in some way?

Comment: ie `:interests[0][1]` etc

Comment: Can you post your updated `def interest` action for me please?

Comment: Ok. I'll edit the post as I think I have made a slight error in my explanation

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation, yesterday. I was drained. Now updated

Comment: You're already using it; just remove the `interest` approach and it should work fine for you

Comment: Thanks again. I'm off to my day job. In the evening I'll report back.

Comment: Ok. I now got `ERROR:  relation "users_supports" does not exist` Where is that coming from?

Comment: You won't have the join table required by your associations

Comment: so remove that line `join_table: :users_supports`?

Comment: It depends on your associations, I don't know what you've got. Yes, removing that switch will likely fix that error but another one will show.

Comment: Too many issues that are in "Chinese" to me. I'll follow the image (appointments etc) you've showed and see how that plays out. Give me a day or two. Thanks

Comment: Rich, I've now used The has_many :through Association approach. All works as it should but I now get duplicate support post after calling the interest method. This part is causing it: `current_user.interests << @support`

Comment: Thank you for your effort and continued support. I've finally understand the rails relation and what I want, and how I want it works perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

To store Hash into column, I suggest you to use "text" instead

```
def change
  add_column :users, :interest, :text
end
```

and then set "serialize" to attribute

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :interest
end
```

once it's done, you can save hash object properly

```
def interest
  @user = User.find(current_user.id ) # I need the logged in user's id
  @support = Support.find(params[:id]) # I need the post's id they are on
  u = FooBar.new
  u.user_id = @user
  u.support_id = @support
  u.save # This saves a new Foo object..this is what I want

  @user.interest = u.attributes # store hash
  @user.save 
end
```

Comment: that gives me `ERROR:  malformed array literal`

Comment: Yes I'm looking at it from my mobile. I'm not at my laptop and I'll try this within the hour. Thanks!

Comment: This keeps overwriting the data when I call the `interest` method. I dont want that.

Answer (score -1):

To convert AR object to hash use `object.attributes`.

To store a custom hash in a model field you can use [serialize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize) or [ActiveRecord::Store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html)

Comment: I'll have a read as im sure it can be done easily. Thanks. But your answer did not work im afraid :(

Answer (score -1):

You can also use to_json method as **object.to_json**

```
User.find(current_user.id ).to_json   # gives a json string
```