# The has_many :through Association - Modification?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have read through the [basics of association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) but my app fits the `has_many :through associations properly...but there is just one issue my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33097689/convert-an-object-to-hash-then-save-it-to-users-column/33099304?noredirect=1#comment54064170_33099304) lacks.

I'd rather ask another question just to keep my question clear and clean.

In my understanding of how the has_many :through associations work is that whenever a doctor has a new patient, a **new** appointment is created or has to be created for that patient. While that perfectly makes sense, [my app](https://gist.github.com/SylarRuby/ff1d756bded295c495f5) dont like that one bit.

In my case, whenever a user 'likes' someone's posts, it creates a new post. I dont want that one bit. I'm trying to get an understanding of the Rails Association so I could answer my other question pertaining to this one. How to prevent another 'appointment' from being automatically created? Or to make perfect sense, when a new instance of `patient` is created and merged into `doctor.patients`, it creates a new appointment.

```
d = Doctor.new
p = Patient.new
a = Appointment.new # created or not

foo = Doctor.find(1)
foo.patients << p # this creates a new appointment which i do not want.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever there is a many-to-many relationship, for instance:

- any single doctor can have multiple patients
- any single patient can have multiple doctors

The database actually needs a third table. This is because we can't put multiple values into a `patient_id` column of the doctor table, and we can't just add on extra columns (how would you know how many to add, and searching would be a nightmare!).

The solution is to create a "join" table, which is simply a table with two columns—in this case `doctor_id` and `patient_id`. If doctor "x" has patients "a", "b", and "c", we can simply add three records to this join table. If patient "a" has two doctors, "x" and "y," we can represent that as well:

**example join table "doctors_patients"**

```
doctor_id | patient_id
    x           a
    x           b
    x           c
    y           a
```

See how that gets around the problem? In the example you cited, the `appointment` table, although it's a model, also acts as the join table for doctors and patients. There's no reason you can't add additional columns such as date, time, room number, etc. on a join table.

**example join table "appointments"**

```
doctor_id | patient_id |  date
    x           a        1/1/2016
    x           b        1/2/2016
    x           c        1/3/2016
    y           a        1/4/2016
```

But if there's no need to refer to a model representing a join table, you can simply use the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association ([see Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)). You still need to make the join table in a migration regardless, as again, you need it in order to represent a many-to-many association, but there's no reason you have to give it a name or represent it with a model.

**Models:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

**Migration:**

```
class CreateUsersAndPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.text :content
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    # This is the join table
    create_table :posts_users, id: false do |t| # posts comes before users alphabetically
      t.belongs_to :posts, index: true
      t.belongs_to :users, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I've just seen the light!! Thanks!!